# Can I restrict a S3 bucket's size?

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket

I've been looking all over and I can't find a yes or no answer. Can I restrict a bucket in S3 to specific size?

If so, could you please point me into the right direction in doing so? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you can do this from within the application you are building, assuming you know the size of the bucket in question, you can use the AWS API for getting the bucket size. However, there seems to be no way to accomplish this from within the AWS dashboard, nor can it be done with an S3 Bucket Policy.

Bummer, because I think this would be a great feature as well.

My advice is to be careful of which applications are uploading content to your S3 bucket, or to interface your application with the AWS API, check the bucket size before inserting content. This is not ideal however.

Comment: 2017 and still no way of restricting the size. This really sucks :/

Comment: 2021 and I didn't found any way of doing this in the S3 console. :-)

Comment: @KhizarIqbal is truly a shame! would be very useful!